# Posuk (Breishis 24:1) said after the end of Hallel on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: minhag, rosh-chodesh-new-month, hallel, parashat-chaye-sara

Artscroll Hebrew Siddurim - and [1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21127&st=&pgnum=357&hilite=) [2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49762&st=&pgnum=588) among others have at the end of Hallel to say the following Posuk.

וְאַבְרָהָם זָקֵן בָּא בַּיָּמִים וַה' בֵּרַךְ אֶת-אַבְרָהָם בַּכֹּל

Artscroll says it is a Segula for Arichas Yomim. Artscroll does not bring a source.

What is the source for saying this Posuk at the end of Hallel? Why specifically on Rosh Chodesh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the passuk says Bo B'yamim it means he aged using every minute of his time and didn't waste any. Maybe we say this because we are starting the new month and we should be reminded once a month how important every minute is like Avraham Avinu did and try to emulate him.

The [Mishnas Chassidim  (Maseches Rosh Chodesh 2:6)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34082&pgnum=210) brings that we say this verse in order to lengthen our days.

Comment: For the last point: [Mishnas Chassidim, Maseches Rosh Chodesh 2:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34082&pgnum=210).